# Raspberry Pi Pycharm can't recognise GPIO

Tags: gpio, python, pi-4

I'm new to Raspberry Pi and Python. I am trying to use Pycharm to code my GPIO just for a simple project to let the led blink. The code is working fine with Thonny IDE but when I move the same code to Pycharm, when I debug my code, the console show me an exception about **No module named 'RPI'**
Then I tried to download the package in my terminal of Raspberry PI controller and the terminal said **"Requirement already satisfied"**.
What can I do in order to use Pycharm to control my GPIO ?
[image: Terminal]
[image: Pycharm Code]
[image: Error Message in Pycharm]

Below is my code:

```
import time
import RPI.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(4, True)
time.sleep(1)
GPIO.output(4, False)
```

It works fine on Thonny but not in Pycharm, I need to use Pycahrm for some reason for my upcoming projects so I need some professional help from you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not post illegible pictures of text; POST TEXT.

Comment: I would also add that in the console `pip` was used so a mix up between Python2 and Python3 can occur when using Thonny. Please take care with this as Python version 3 should be used for all new projects (2 is going away) so `pip3 install xyz` and `python3 xyz.py` are the two commands to use in the console.  Also check that any editors are set up to use Python 3 by default - PyCharm can use multiple versions in its virtual environments - see gif https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/

Comment: Don't use `pip` use `pip3` as everything you're doing should be run with python3. Also with RaspiOS the RPi.GPIO

Answer (score 1):

Python is case sensitive, and you misspelled/capitalized the module name.

Change:

```
import RPI.GPIO as GPIO
```

to:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

Note: the lowercase i.